# How to share a service between project and library in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I want to share my service to library because in library i want some api call. The api services are given in the project

```
The api service given in the project

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MasterApiService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getById(tbl: string, id: string | number) {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/getById/${tbl}/${id}`).toPromise();
  }
}



Its my library service i want above service instance in library 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedLibraryService {

  constructor() {}
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

you can Import and Use the Shared Service in the Library:

```
...
import { SharedLibraryService } from '../../shared.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [SharedLibraryService],
})
export class MyLibraryModule {}
```

then Import the Library Module in the Project:

```
...
import { MyLibraryModule } from 'path-to-my-library'; // Replace 'path-to-my-library' with the actual path to your library

@NgModule({
  imports: [MyLibraryModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now, you can use the SharedLibraryService in your project components and services as well as inside the library components and services.

Comment: 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
I alredy tried but this error is show